# How to import eclipse.org libraries in java swing project developed in neatbeans IDE

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to import the following libraries in my project, How to to do it?

```
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttCallback;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttConnectOptions;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttDeliveryToken;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttMessage;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttTopic;
```

I have to download files? or I have to make link to eclipse.org? how to import it? Any hint. Thank you.

Comment: are you using any build tools? ei: maven, gradle, etc

Comment: I suggest reading the documentation here: https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/java/

Comment: I developed an app in java swing using neatbeans IDE and now want to add mqtt for communication with remote server. So trying to get that.

Comment: @JohnKane Can you please elaborate about build tools? what is it used for?.

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation for Eclipse Paho](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/java/) explains exactly what to do:

> Eclipse hosts a Nexus repository for those who want to use Maven to manage their dependencies. The released libraries are also available in the Maven Central repository.
>
> Add the repository definition and the dependency definition shown below to your pom.xml.
>
> Replace %REPOURL% with either https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-releases/ for the official releases, or https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-snapshots/ for the nightly snapshots. Replace %VERSION% with the level required . The latest release version is 1.0.2 and the current snapshot version is 1.0.3.

```
<project ...>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>Eclipse Paho Repo</id>
        <url>%REPOURL%</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
...
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.paho</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3</artifactId>
        <version>%VERSION%</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. but I am not using Maven for management of dependencies. I developed an application in swing using neatbeans IDE.

Comment: How to deal with that. Regards.

Comment: @john I suggest that you start using Maven

Comment: Okay, Thank you.

Comment: As per docs of Maven: Apache Maven is a free and open source project management tool used for Java projects. You can easily manage a project's build, reporting, and documentation from a central piece of information using Apache Maven. Apache Maven provides a complete framework to automate the project's build infrastructure.

Comment: How its related to import of libraries?

Comment: @john You create a .pom file that tells Maven which libraries to download for your project so that you can import them into your code. This is what the documentation means by "manage a project's build".

Answer (score 0):

- Download jar files of the required libraries, for example,
  Pahomqtt.jar folder.
- In neatbeans, Go to the libraries of your project in neatbeans -> Right click -> Add
  Jar/Folder -> Navigate to downloaded jar folder -> add -> Done.